# Hover 1st DIV affect all other 1st DIVS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm asking a basic question here, for some reason I can't get it to work. Any help will be appreciated.

Here's what I'm trying to do using either CSS or JQUERY
http://css-tricks.com/examples/RowColumnHighlighting/example-two.php

Basicaly I have:

```
<div class="block1">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="block2">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="block3">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="block4">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to hover the first div in any of the blocks and all the other first div will be highlighted as well. Same thing for the second or third div of each block.
I hope I'm explaining this correctly.

If there's any other related post I don't mind.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You should be using tables for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here we go. working jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/fLkRQ/

```
$("div[class^='block']").children('div').hover(function(e){

    var index = $(this).index();
    $("div[class ^='block']").children('div').each(function(){
    if ($(this).index() == index){
        $(this).addClass('highligted')
    } else {
     $(this).removeClass('highligted');
    }
})                        
})
```

you should use jQuery index() method. Read more here - http://api.jquery.com/index/ 
Hope this helps

Comment: OMG, that is fantastic, thank you very much. I will take a look on jquery index.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
div.block1:hover>div *{
    color:red;
}

div.block1 div:hover>div *{
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you understood the question.